# Difference between KeyRange and KeySlice in astayanx APIs

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, astyanax

What is the difference between KeyRange and KeySlice APIs in Astyanax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [Astyanax documentation](http://netflix.github.io/astyanax/javadoc/com/netflix/astyanax/query/ColumnFamilyQuery.html), it looks like `getKeyRange` retrieves data based on a range of two keys.  Essentially, this is equivalent of a key-based greater-than/less-than query.

Additionally, `getKeySlice` retrieves data based on a specific list of (non-contiguous) keys.  This would be equivalent to querying for data having a key present `IN` the list.

Their [GitHub "Getting Started" page](https://github.com/Netflix/astyanax/wiki/Getting-Started) has an example of how to use getKeySlice under "Reading a set of non-contiguous rows."

```
OperationResult<Rows<String, String>> result =
  ks.prepareQuery(CF_STANDARD1)
    .getKeySlice("Key1", "Key2", "Key3")
    .execute();
```

Check the documentation (linked above) for more information.